# Crashing while calling a Action button from SecondViewController.view in XCode6 Swift

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8, xcode6

While calling a action button from the SecondViewController.view gives runtime error in the **XCode6 (Beta) / Swift environment**. Please refer the below for more details.

My Scenario is like the below

1. Trying to call FirstView Screen from the ‘**didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**’
   with the below works fine.

   ```
   var varFirstViewController:firstViewController?= firstViewController(nibName:"firstViewController", bundle: nil)
   self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:varFirstViewController)
   self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController"
   ```
2. From the FirstViewController.view I am trying to call second view controller by the below code works fine

   ```
   let sec: SecondViewController = SecondViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.view.addSubview(sec.view)
   ```
3. From the secondViewController.view trying to trigger a ActionButton throws RunTime Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Appreciate your expertise on this.